# Flutter: The value passed in parameter is null on the second page the first time

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

Flutter: The value passed in parameter is null on the second page the first time. if I do a hot reload, this value is not null.

maybe it's because of the TabBar but how do you get the real value for the first time while using TabBar?

Please help me find a solution to my problem

First page. And idBou is not null here

```
class BoutiquePage extends StatefulWidget {
  int idboutique;

  BoutiquePage({this.idboutique});

  @override
  _BoutiquePageState createState() => _BoutiquePageState();
}

class _BoutiquePageState extends State<BoutiquePage> {

  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
 
  
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  String idBou ;
  String nomAbon ;
  String prenomAbon ;
  String telAbon ;
  String addAbon;
  String nomBou;
  String ville;
  String pays;

  String lien_photo_bout;


  bool _isLoading = false;


  String _errorText;

  get article_afficher333 => article_afficher333;

  @override
  void initState() { 
    setState((){ 
      getShaerInstance();
    }); 
    super.initState();
  }
  getShaerInstance() async {
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance(); 
  }


    Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getAllStoreInfoData2(int idboutique) async {
      final response = await http.get(http://xxxxxx.com+"boutique/home?id_bout="+idboutique.toString()); 
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
        BoutiqueData myData = new BoutiqueData.fromJson(jsonResponse);
        
        Map<String, dynamic> boutiqueinfodata = Map();
        boutiqueinfodata["boutiqueType"] = myData.v_boutique.typeBoutique; 
        return boutiqueinfodata;

      } else {
        throw Exception("Failed to load Data");
      }
    }

   
  //SharedPreferences

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Widget myboutiqueinfodata = FutureBuilder(
      future: getAllStoreInfoData2(widget.idboutique),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          Map<String, dynamic> alldata = snapshot.data;          
          typeBoutique = alldata["boutiqueType"];        
          List<ListeInfoBoutique> boutiqueInfoData = alldata["boutiqueInfoData"];   
           
            for (var i = 0; i < boutiqueInfoData.length; i++) {
              idBou = boutiqueInfoData[i].idBou;
              nomAbon = boutiqueInfoData[i].nomAbon;
              prenomAbon = boutiqueInfoData[i].prenomAbon;
              telAbon = boutiqueInfoData[i].telAbon;
              addAbon = boutiqueInfoData[i].addAbon; 
            }

            return   Scaffold(
                body: ListView(
                  children: <Widget>[
                     
                  ],
                ),
              );



        }else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)
                      .translate('_MSG_ER_CONNEXION_CHARGE_DATA'), 
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                    fontFamily: 'Questrial'
                                  ),),
            ),
          );
        }
        return new Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      });

    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 5,
      child: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)
                        .translate('_MY_STORE'), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontFamily: "Questrial"),),
            iconTheme: new IconThemeData(color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF)),
            actions: <Widget>[

              //
            ],
            bottom: TabBar(
              isScrollable: true,
              indicatorColor: Colors.white,
              indicatorWeight: 5.0,
              //onTap: (){},
              tabs: <Widget>[
                Tab(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)
                        .translate('_STORE_INFO'), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18.0, fontFamily: 'Questrial'),),
                  ),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)
                        .translate('_MY_ARTICLES'), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18.0, fontFamily: 'Questrial'),),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
                myboutiqueinfodata, 
                MesArticles(idboutique: idBou),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }

    }
```

Secode page who print null a first time and after hot reload become not null

```
class MesArticles extends StatefulWidget {
  final String idboutique;
  const MesArticles({Key key, this.idboutique}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MesArticleState createState() => _MesArticleState();
}

class _MesArticleState extends State<MesArticles> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   print(widget.idboutique.toString()); // it print null for fist time. After hot reload it become not null
    return Scaffold(
      body: Text(widget.idboutique.toString()), //<== it print null for fist time.
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. I think Future builder is the reason it throws null.

```dart
class BoutiquePage extends StatefulWidget {
  int idboutique;

  BoutiquePage({this.idboutique});

  @override
  _BoutiquePageState createState() => _BoutiquePageState();
}

class _BoutiquePageState extends State<BoutiquePage> {

  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
 
  
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  String idBou ;
  String nomAbon ;
  String prenomAbon ;
  String telAbon ;
  String addAbon;
  String nomBou;
  String ville;
  String pays;

  String lien_photo_bout;


  bool _isLoading = false;
  bool _isLoaded = false;
  bool _isError = false;


  String _errorText;

  get article_afficher333 => article_afficher333;

  @override
  void initState() { 
    setState((){ 
      getShaerInstance();
    }); 
    super.initState();
  }
  getShaerInstance() async {
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance(); 
  }


    Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getAllStoreInfoData2(int idboutique) async {
      final response = await http.get("http://xxxxxx.com/" + "boutique/home?id_bout="+idboutique.toString()); 
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
        BoutiqueData myData = new BoutiqueData.fromJson(jsonResponse);
        
        Map<String, dynamic> boutiqueinfodata = Map();
        boutiqueinfodata["boutiqueType"] = myData.v_boutique.typeBoutique; 
        return boutiqueinfodata;

      } else {
        throw Exception("Failed to load Data");
      }
    }

   
  //SharedPreferences

  initDataFromServer(idboutique) async {

    try {


    var alldata = await  getAllStoreInfoData2(idboutique);         
          var typeBoutique = alldata["boutiqueType"];        
          List<ListeInfoBoutique> boutiqueInfoData = alldata["boutiqueInfoData"];   
           
            for (var i = 0; i < boutiqueInfoData.length; i++) {
              idBou = boutiqueInfoData[i].idBou;
              nomAbon = boutiqueInfoData[i].nomAbon;
              prenomAbon = boutiqueInfoData[i].prenomAbon;
              telAbon = boutiqueInfoData[i].telAbon;
              addAbon = boutiqueInfoData[i].addAbon; 
            }

        setState(() {
          _isLoaded = true;
          _isLoading = false;
          _isError = false;
        });

    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      setState(() {
        _isLoaded = true;
        _isLoading = true;
        _isError = true;
      });
    }
    
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_isLoaded == false && _isLoading == false) {
      _isLoading = true;
      initDataFromServer(widget.idboutique);
    }

    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 5,
      child: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)
                        .translate('_MY_STORE'), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontFamily: "Questrial"),),
            iconTheme: new IconThemeData(color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF)),
            actions: <Widget>[

              //
            ],
            bottom: TabBar(
              isScrollable: true,
              indicatorColor: Colors.white,
              indicatorWeight: 5.0,
              //onTap: (){},
              tabs: <Widget>[
                Tab(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)
                        .translate('_STORE_INFO'), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18.0, fontFamily: 'Questrial'),),
                  ),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)
                        .translate('_MY_ARTICLES'), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18.0, fontFamily: 'Questrial'),),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
                _isLoaded == false ? Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ): (_isError == false ? Text("Your data Loaded") : Text("Error")),
        
                _isLoaded == false ? Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ): (_isError == false ? MesArticles(idboutique: idboutique) : Text("Error")), 
                
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }

    }
```

```dart
class MesArticles extends StatefulWidget {
  final String idboutique;
  const MesArticles({Key key, this.idboutique}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MesArticleState createState() => _MesArticleState(idboutique: idboutique);
}

class _MesArticleState extends State<MesArticles> {
  final String idboutique;

  _MesArticleState({this.idboutique});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   print(widget.idboutique.toString()); // it print null for fist time. After hot reload it become not null
    return Scaffold(
      body: Text(widget.idboutique.toString()),
    );
  }
}
```